# How to switch to predict mode in Trax after training a model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, trax

I'm familiarizing myself with the Trax library for building deep learning models and one question that I can't find an answer to is how to switch from "train" mode to "eval" mode after model training is complete.

Consider this example with a transformer (modified from https://github.com/google/trax#1-run-a-pre-trained-transformer)

```
import trax

model = trax.models.Transformer(
    input_vocab_size=33300,
    d_model=512, d_ff=2048,
    n_heads=8, n_encoder_layers=6, n_decoder_layers=6,
    max_len=2048, mode='train')

# do the training
```

After the training, how can I switch the mode to be "predict"?

One idea that comes to mind (following the same example), is to train the model, then save it, re-initialize the model but this time with `mode='train'` and then load the weights by running `model.init_from_file(file)`.

Is there a way to do it directly without having to re-init the model?